# Determine what CSS selectors are been applied to an element

Tags: javascript, css, dom

Is there a way do determine if a selector is currently been applied to an given element?

I know it´s possible to iterate over all CSS selectors, and test if each one is applicably or not. But I´m not sure if this is the way that Firebug and other inspector do it.

**EDIT:**
I need a way to do it dynamically, with JS.

Comment: The console and javascript are two different things, there's no guarantee that you can do the same thing with javascript that the console does inside the browser enviroment.

Comment: adeneo, I think Firebug do that kind of inspection with DOM API.

Comment: maybe mark "I need a way to do it dynamically, with JS." with an **EDIT** so that people stop downvoting the original (good for the original question) answers?

Comment: @Adilson you want to get applied css on given element by javascript?

Comment: Yes, it should be done with Javascript. I marked the question with #JavaScript originally.

Comment: *"I know it´s possible to iterate over all CSS selectors, and test if each one is applicably or not."* I think that's the only way to do it.

Comment: I would up-vote this *twice* just because you mentioned needing to do this *dynamically*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if an element instance is matched by a selector by using [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
function elementMatchesSelector(element, selector) {
    return Array.prototype.indexOf.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector), element) > -1;
}
```

Of course this only works for modern browsers that support the aforementioned methods.

---

Alternatively you can use [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches):

```
function elementMatchesSelector(element, selector) {
    var fn;
    if (!element) {
        return false;
    }
    fn = element.matches || element.mozMatchesSelector || element.msMatchesSelector || element.webkitMatchesSelector;
    if (fn) {
        return fn.call(element, selector);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You can also use `element.matches(selector)`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches.

Comment: @FelixKling, that's good to know. The browser-specific prefixes make the code a bit awkward, but it's probably a better choice than what i've written here, as it appears to have the same level of browser support.

Comment: That is the solution I thought initially. Iterate over document.styleSheets, and for each cssRule test if it match with my elmeent. But, even so, it would be necessary to check the CSS rules priorities.

Comment: I´ll check Firebug source later to see if they use another approach. Thanks, anyway!

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr, calculating a selector's specificity isn't all *that* difficult, but you do need to be able to parse the selector.

Answer (score 1):

In Firebug, you can look at the [**Computed Side Panel**](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Computed_Side_Panel). For any given DOM element, it shows the CSS styles applied (even those applied via JavaScript). It also depicts the styles that were *overridden*. From the docs:

> The Computed Side Panel shows all CSS style values calculated by the user agent while interpreting the given CSS information for the selected node inside the HTML Panel.

[image]

Comment: But, with JS, how can I do it?

Comment: The question is how to do this *"dynamically, with JS"*. This is not a JavaScript solution.

Comment: @Joeytje50, if you took a look at the [edits to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21488253/revisions), you'd already have noticed that the requirement regarding JS was added only _after_ this answer was posted. I'm well aware this is not a JS solution, thank you.

Comment: @zeantsoi okay, sorry, I didn't realise that. By the way, I'm not the one who downvoted you.

Comment: @Joeytje50, I never thought you were. FWIW, downvotes don't elicit a response from me, anyways.

Comment: I edited the question again to better explicit the JS requirement. Anyway, the question was marked with #JavaScript when I posted it.

Comment: I down voted on the basis the OP asked for a javascript solution, but sadly didn't see the edit. Down vote removed.

Comment: @AdilsondeAlmeidaJr, I find it curious that you'd add a tag, but not explain your requirements _in any depth_ in the question. Perhaps I'll begin answering questions based purely on their tags... but I probably won't.

Answer (score 0):

What about using getComputedStyle()
[MDN Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle)

Comment: This returns the style rules, not the selectors.